# MySQL: delete duplicate rows, keep none

Tags: mysql

newbie here, for this table I would like to remove all ID's (rows) that don't have a unique number in Event. So far I found only solutions that will keep one ID, but remove the duplicates.

```
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    | ID        | Costs        |   Date   | Event  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     1     |      100     |2012/09/10|  5     |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     2     |      300     |2012/09/20|  5     |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     3     |      400     |2012/10/01|  4     |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

I have tried the `ALTER IGNORE TABLE ADD UNIQUE INDEX` function, but i don't want to keep one ID. For example, in this table I would like to remove the rows from ID 1 and 2, but keep ID 3.

Note: all ID's are unique.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HAVING to get Event that has duplicate value, then use it in DELETE query instead of using the ID in WHERE criteria, isn't it?